# Spring JDBC queryForObject with BigDecimal fails

Tags: java, exception, spring-jdbc

> Java 1.7/Spring 3.1

Have a look at below code.

```
BigDecimal value = queryAsObject (BigDecimal.class, 
    "select balance from financial.accounts where account_id = ?", accountId);
```

Where queryAsObject comes from an abstract parent class which basically does CRUD operations.

```
public <T> T queryAsObject(Class<T> modelClass, String sql, Object... args) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new HawkBeanPropertyRowMapper<T>(modelClass), args);
    }
```

Pretty straight forward spring jdbc call. However it results in below exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception in org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Could not instantiate bean class [java.math.BigDecimal]: 
Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is 
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.math.BigDecimal
```

With Root cause:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.math.BigDecimal]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: java.math.BigDecimal
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:81)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper.mapRow(BeanPropertyRowMapper.java:233)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:1)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:734)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, Object... args)` is for binding the ResultSet to Beans/POJOs.

You need the other overloaded version `queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType, Object... args)`, i.e.

```
public <T> T queryAsScalar(Class<T> scalarClass, String sql, Object... args) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, scalarClass, args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be using a subclass of `BeanPropertyMapper`. It treats the class provided as a Java bean, instantiating it by a call to the default constructor and then setting the properties by calling the setters. `java.math.BigDecimal` does not have a default constructor and that's where it fails.

You should use `queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType, Object... args)` method instead.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation and it definitely make sense.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely works

```
JdbcTemplate t = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
BigDecimal id = t.queryForObject("select id from bank where id=1", BigDecimal.class);
```